# Snow leopard GUI parts?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, osx-snow-leopard

Many apps which were released in these years have new looking gui parts.
Vertical layouted min, max and close buttons in iTunes or Twitter.app(But latest one has default layout) , Tab control in Safari and Terminal, sliders in GarageBand and iMovie...

I can't find these new gui parts in interface builder.
How can I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those new looking GUI parts belong to the individual applictions, most of them can't be accessed via API. You'd have to write them yourselves.

For some popular GUI parts there are third party libraries available however.

Comment: I see. I hope those parts will be included in 10.7.

Answer (score 4):

see http://cocoacontrols.com/ for cocoa controls